# How can I print an array of strings that also has double variables?

Tags: java

***EDITED to remove excess code and show the exact errors I am receiving.***

I am attempting to show my array in a grid format (like a spreadsheet).  I have declared it an array of strings, so that I can use readLine and split however 6 out of 7 columns are doubles. 
I keep getting incompatible types errors on all of the array variables. 
More specifically: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to string, incomparable types int and string and incompatible types string cannot be converted to double I am new and when I researched on here, I couldn't find how to fix this.
Here is my code:

```
         while(s != null) {
          array = s.split(delimiter);
          dates = array[0];
          dates = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
          double[] nums = new double[array.length];
          for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
          nums[i] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
          }       
          if(dates != 0)  {
            open = array[1];
            high = array[2];
            low = array[3];
            close = array[4];
            adjClose = array[5];
            volume = array[6];
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message and remove those bits of code which are not directly relevant to the said error.

Comment: `open = Double.parseDouble(array[1]);`

Comment: Why assign something the to `dates` variable (`dates = array[0]`), then immediately replace it with something else (`dates = Integer.parseInt(array[0])`)? If text stored in `array[0]` is supposed to be an integer number, why is `dates` type `String`, and not type `int`? If you know that `array[0]` is not a `double` value, why does your loop calling `parseDouble()` start at index 0? If you already parsed all the values to `double`, why are you trying to assign `array[1]` to `open`, not `nums[1]`? Same question for indexes 2-6?

Comment: A `String` doesn't become a `double` just because you've assigned a `String` value to a `double` variable.

Comment: I thought that I converted it to a double with Double.parseDouble?

Comment: In your original version, you declared `String[] array` but `double open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, and others.  (Aside: Please [edit] those declarations back in --- they were important.)  But, as Silvio Mayolo pointed out, you tried to assign strings from `array` directly to variables like `high` and `low`.  That's what I was referring to.  Although you did convert those strings with `Double.parseDouble`, you did not _use_ the converted values --- they were all in `double[] nums`, not `String[] array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is a *statically typed language*. You can't just take a string and pretend it's a double. A `String[]` variable is *always* going to contain strings. It might contain strings that look like doubles, but they will always be strings.

```
String[] array = ...;
double x = array[0];
```

This is a type error because we're extracting a string from the array and asking the system to simply pretend it's a double, which it won't do.

```
String[] array = ...;
double x = Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
```

This will convert the string value to a double. If the data you're getting is from a trusted source (for instance, if it's for a class and your teacher promised the data would be valid), then that's fine. But if the data is coming from a user or other source, `Double.parseDouble` will throw an exception if the data is invalid, and you need to think about the correct way to handle that in your particular case.

For the sake of completeness, here is the opposite conversion.

```
String string = x.toString();
```

Any object (and, through a trick of the Java compiler, any primitive as well) can have `toString` called on it, and this will turn the object into a string.

Comment: Also, most 'raw' types (int, double, boolean, etc.) don't have a .toString() method that you can call directly (although it does get handled sometimes behind-the-scenes.) However, their related Object class versions should have a static method that can be called: Integer.toString(someInt), Double.toString(someDouble), etc.

Comment: I think you can use `String.valueOf` to convert those raw types to string if needed